# 421 Rejected command, requested IP address does not match control connection IP

Tags: linux, ftp

Linux Mint 20

I try to connect see content on folder on the ftp like this:

```
ftp 172.18.xx.xx
Connected to 172.18.xx.xx.
220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
Name (172.18.xx.xx:alex): root
331 Password required for root
Password:
230 Logged on
Remote system type is UNIX.

ftp> ls
421 Rejected command, requested IP address does not match control connection IP.
```

Comment: What’s Linux here? Client? Server? Both? Which FTP client are you using? Is it set to Passive FTP?

Comment: @DanielB Client - Linux Mint 20.3. Use embedded ftp

Comment: What “embedded ftp”? I’m not following. Please provide the name of an Mint/Ubuntu package that is your FTP client.